# Sharing mp4 with easy share action with Android app from Media Library

Tags: android, facebook, video, mp4, android-sharing

I have an app which I want to store audio files in mp4 format in a folder of my choice. 
I want to share some of them in Facebook but I dont have the facebook option while if I have a mp4 video file in my device's media library, I have full list of options and facebook, and I have the mp4 video file ready to be shared.

Why is that? Do I have to add some extra info while saving them on the first place?

Do I have to save them in main device media library?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put an image or video while recording because in some way the system knows it is just an audio so even if you copy the audio mp4 to the main media library you won't see any difference